# How do I solve the problem?: You don't have an extension for debugging Python. Should we find a Python extension in the Marketplace?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

When I run python from vscode liveshare it says 'You don't have an extension for debugging Python. Should we find a Python extension in the Marketplace?’.

The problem appeared despite completely deleting and reinstalling vscode and reinstalling the python extension.

[extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqjbx.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3usqp.png)

[version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THbN1.png)

Comment: maybe it is a problem that you are using 3.12 and it might be too new. What python extention did you install?

Comment: I installed python(Microsoft)

Comment: ok could be correct. have you tried an earlier version of python, you seem to be new to the community and the 3.12 is likely not necessary for you yet

Comment: I am using python 3.10.12

Comment: you are most certainly not. Look at the bottom right corner of your screen. It says 3.12.0

click on it and switch to 3.10 or even install 3.10 in the first place

Comment: I changed the version to 3.10.12 but it still doesn't work.

Comment: is it the same error?

Comment: yes it is the same error

Comment: your extension screenshot shows a warning sign next to the Python extension. what do you see when you hover over the warning sign or click the extension?

Comment: pylance -  Analysis is limited to opened files.
python -  Only Partial IntelliSense supported.

Comment: Are you using a local workspace instead of remoting?

Comment: [A similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18686) on github. This was caused by liveshare.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18686).

> This is because Liveshare uses a virtual file system when the files
> you're working on aren't local, and supporting complete intelliSense
> on a virtual file system isn't feasible atm. Closing this as it is
> working as expected.

You can try to disable **Live Share extension** then rerun python file.